# HTML Beautify - Angular Directive

Tags: angularjs, js-beautify

I would like to use HTML Beautify against an Angular partial to allow me to present to my client a code snippet of the partial.

The issue I'm running into is that when I beautify the partial to ensure formatting is correct, my directives, that have no arguments are being changed to have a blank ="".

For example:

```
<div my-directive></div>
```

Is beautified into

```
<div my-directive=""></div>
```

Is there an option I can send to HTML Beautify that will not force the addition of ="" to my directive?

Comment: try a different beautifier maybe? I don't know of the default options, but if you look at the source code you can probably find the logic for it. Which beautifier are you using?

Comment: I'm using js-beautify.  I feel like there should be an option to do what I want, but when looking at the source it isn't jumping out at at me.